# XSL for loop node pattern

Tags: xml, regex, xslt

I have the following XML node:

```
<parent>
   <child1name>value</child1name>
   <child2name>value</child2name>
   <child3name>value</child3name>
   <child4name>value</child4name>
   <others />
</parent>
```

I want to loop through each node with name formatted as text[digit]text.
So I did:

```
<xsl:for-each select="parent/child*name">
   Value <xsl:value-of select="position()" />: <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

But it didn't work.

What would be the correct pattern? `"child\d{1}name"` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

A correct pattern would be

```
<xsl:for-each select="parent/*[starts-with(./name(),'child')]">
```

Else, if you need a tougher restriction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="parent/*[starts-with(./name(),'child') and ends-with(./name(),'name')]">
```

Besides, it is not good practice to incorporate text in a stylesheet like this. Rather, you would enclose any text in `xsl:text` elements.

An entire stylesheet that works with the input snippet you have shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="parent/*[starts-with(./name(),'child') and ends-with(./name(),'name')]">
  <xsl:text>Value </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
  <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives the following output:

```
Value 1: value
Value 2: value
Value 3: value
Value 4: value
```

Comment: When deploying it tells me:
ERROR:  'Sintax error 'root/parent/*[starts-with(./name(),'node')]'.'

Comment: It works with XSLT 2.0 and Saxon 9.1. What do you work with? Also, I did not write `starts-with(./name(),'node')`.

Comment: I know, I know
I'm working with 1.0
It deploys correctly with "[starts-with(name(), 'child')]", but no node was retrieved, I've tested it with count()

Comment: This solution does exactly what you have asked. Of course, if you change the requirements (i.e. include more code or change the structure of input XML) - then it is not guaranteed to work anymore.

Comment: Yep, let's suppose that what I'm looking for is a solution, not the solution. Let's also suppose that because of confidential issues I'm not available to post a full example. Then, suppose where I've said "parent" I was meaning "path with some nodes", and of course, let's suppose that I'm not working with your code requirements (version) and you give crossover version solution. Thanks.

Comment: This also works with XSLT 1.0 - so, no need to devise another solution. I can only repeat myself: If your XML is confidential, show an XML that at least has the same _structure_ as your actual data. Then you will have less trouble adjusting my answer to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the XML structure. For me it is easier to run through the child-elements without pattern like:

```
<parent>
  <childs>
    <child>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>value</name>
    </child>
    <child>
      <id>2</id>
  <name>value</name>
    </child>
    <child>
      <id>3</id>
  <name>value</name>
    </child>
    <child>
      <id>4</id>
  <name>value</name>
    </child>
   </childs>
   <others />
 </parent>
```

I think the structure is more clearly and just a differnt approach.

regards

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot change XML structure.